# "Did not find target for sync message for x" What does this mean and how can i solve it

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm currently making a multiplayer game in unity but I'm getting this warning on the client but not the host it seems to be something to do with Destroy(gameObject); as its happening when an object is destroyed but it doesn't always seem to pop up when an item is destroyed.

- Is "Did not find target for sync message for x" something I should worry about and spend and focus on fixing.
- Is there another way to destroy a gameObject and not have this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That message means that Unity's network engine received an update for some object that doesn't seem to exist.

This could be a problem because it indicates that the server and client(s) are out of sync -- in this case, they no longer agree about which objects do or do not exist in the scene. Imagine, for example, that one of your players is hit and injured by a rocket that "doesn't exist" on their screen.

If it's an unimportant, purely cosmetic object that went missing, you might reconsider whether that object needs to be network-synced at all.

If it's an important object that went missing, you should [review the object's lifecycle](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNetSpawning.html). Is it being created with `NetworkServer.Spawn` and destroyed with `NetworkServer.Destroy`? If not, you're likely going to end up with errors.

Comment: I have been using 'NetworkServer.Spawn' And tried using 'NetworkServer,Destroy' but am still getting the warning could it be caused by the object calling it on multiple clients. 

Currently the object checks how far it moves since it has spawned and once it reaches a certain distance it calls 'NetworkServer.Destroy' on itself. 

Is there a way to make it so it only calls it on the client it was created on or the hosts client.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the Network Send Rate to 0 resolved the issue for me.  In my case, the objects causing the problem was a projectile (fire and forget).

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that receives this error, here's a simple thing that might cause it:

I had two NetworkTransformChild components that tried to access two disabled GameObjects. Be sure that every enabled Networkcomponent is able to access their specified gameobject/component.